# Ajax Pagination with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I need to retrieve data from an api that has a limit on the number of results being returned.

Using the total number of results found, I'm able to make additional additional ajax calls until all data is retrieved.  However, I need sort all the data alphabetically before displaying it on the page.

How can I access the data within the array after ALL ajax calls have been successfully made?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var mydata = [];

function loadPosts() {

  var api = 'http://someurl.com';

  $.ajax({
    url: api,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      rows: 1,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      totalNumberOfRecords = data.numFound;

      for (var start = 0; start < totalNumberOfRecords; start += rows) {
        $.ajax({
          url: api,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          data: {
            'rows': rows,
            'start': start,
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.namesList, function(index, item) {
              mydata.push(item.firstName);
            });
          },
        });
      }
    },
  });
}

console.log(mydata);
```

Comment: Oh. Callback hell. You shouldn't use ajax in a loop. Ajax is async promise. You can find some idea solution with keyword: async waterfall (nodejs async library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instant-noodle solution.

```
var numOfAjax = 0;
var numOfResolvedAjax = 0;
for (var start = 0; start < totalNumberOfRecords; start += rows) {
    numOfAjax++;
    $.ajax({
        url: api,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            'rows': rows,
            'start': start,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.namesList, function(index, item) {
                mydata.push(item.firstName);
            });
            numOfResolvedAjax++;

            // Check if all ajax request has been responded to sort the result.
            if (numOfResolvedAjax === numOfAjax) {
                sortMyData(myData);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

For a perfect solution, please check in [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library with a lot of functions which can help you. E.g: [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if it were me with this API limit issue, I'd use the server to talk to the API ever-so-often to capture all the data into my own system - beit MySQL or Redis or whatever. Then I would use my front-end JS however I wanted without limmits